# Virtualbox can't find USB devices

Tags: usb, virtualbox, virtualization

I am using Virtualbox 6.0. The problem is it can't recognize any of my USB devices. I already installed an extension pack, the same version as VirtualBox and tried to make my account a member of `vboxusers` using the following command `sudo adduser $USER vboxusers` but unfortunately, nothing is working.

How can I solve this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you rebooted after running the `sudo adduser $USER vboxusers`?

Comment: Yes, I rebooted

Comment: Does your VM launch OK?  If it doesn't, get a listing of the `/usr` folder as `ls -la /usr` and make sure that all folders are owned by root just in that folder.  Sometimes I have seen 3 of the folders in there become owned by my user account for whatever reason then VirtualBox has problems.  If the ownership ever changes, only change the ownership of the folders and not the sub-folders.

Comment: Thanks for your support. likely I fixed it. The problem was I added root to vboxusers but not my current account. After adding my current account to the vboxusers group everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting the first option: *Settings* -> *USB* -> *Enable USB Controller* -> select USB 1.1 (OHCI) Controller. That may work for now until an update to VirtualBox restores full USB functionality.

[image: Settings]

Comment: not work on ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 8):

Five conditions must exist for USB devices to show up in Windows in VirtualBox running under Linux.

1. Extension pack and VirtualBox versions must **match**. The former can be found via File > Preferences > Extensions and the latter via Help > About.
2. USB Controller must be enabled in the VM configuration options.
3. VBox Guest Additions must be installed on the guest VM. With the VM running, click Devices > Insert Guest Additions CD Image and run the VBoxWindowsAdditions executable.
4. The user running VirtualBox must be in the **vboxusers** group. At the command line, run `groups` to see what groups you are a member of. If vboxusers isn't in the list, run `sudo gpasswd -a $USER vboxusers` to add yourself then REBOOT.
5. At least one filter must be set up under Devices > USB > USB Settings. Clicking the top icon on the right (USB plug with solid blue dot) will create a 'universal' filter for any device. When the VM is running, you should now see a list when you go to Devices > USB that allows you to select devices to connect.